# Why am I getting an error when trying to join tables in my SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have written the query below to gather data relating to truck driver revenue.  Both the main query and the joined query work properly. However, when I combine them, I get an error

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
>   The multi-part identifier "tn.ctripnumber" could not be bound

relating to `tRev.ctripnumber = tn.ctripnumber`. I have tried using the revenue table name as well as the tRev alias.

```
select 
    tn.ctripnumber as "Load Number",
    tr.cresourcedesc as "Carrier/Driver",
    tr.resourcetype as "Resource Type",
    tn.cfirmorigin as "Pickup Origin",
    tn.corigaddress as "Origin Address",
    tn.corigcity as "Origin City",
    tn.corigstate as "Origin State",
    tn.corigzip as "Origin Zip",
    tn.dorigappt_start as "Scheduled Arrival Date",
    tn.dorigappt_end as "Scheduled Late Arrival Date",
    tn.dtripstartdate as "Actual Arrival Date",
    datediff(minute,tn.dorigappt_start,tn.dtripstartdate) as "Arrival Diff",
    (case when tn.dtripstartdate-tn.dorigappt_start < 0 then 'Early' when tn.dorigappt_start-tn.dtripstartdate = 0 then 'On-time' else 'Late' end) as Arrival_Rank,
    tn.cfirmdestination as "Delivery Destination",
    tn.cdestaddress as "Destination Address",
    tn.cdestcity as "Destination City",
    tn.cdeststate as "Destination State",
    tn.cdestzip as "Destination Zip",
    tn.ddestappt_start as "Scheduled Delivery Date",
    tn.ddestappt_end as "Scheduled Late Delivery Date",
    tn.ddeliverydate as "Actual Delivery Date",
    datediff(minute,tn.ddestappt_start,tn.ddeliverydate) as "Delivery Diff",
    (case when tn.ddeliverydate-tn.ddestappt_start < 0 then 'Early' when tn.ddeliverydate-tn.ddestappt_start = 0 then 'On-time' else 'Late' end) as "Delivery Rank",
    tn.nideadheadmiles as "Deadhead Miles",
    tn.niloadedmiles as "Loaded Miles",
    tn.nideadheadmiles + tn.niloadedmiles as "Total Miles"
from 
    tripnumber tn,tripresources tr
inner join
    (select  
         r.ctripnumber, sum(Revenue_Subtotal) as "Revenue" 
     from 
         (select 
              r.ctripnumber, r.cmethod, sum(r.curevenue) as Revenue_Subtotal
          from 
              revenuedtl r 
          where 
              r.cmethod in (select distinct r.cmethod from revenuedtl r)
          group by 
              r.ctripnumber, r.cmethod) r
     --where r.cmethod like 'BROK%'
     group by 
         r.ctripnumber) tRev on tRev.ctripnumber = tn.ctripnumber
where 
    tn.ctripnumber = tr.ctripnumber
    --and tn.ctripnumber = '324412'
    and tr.resourcetype in ('D','M')
    and tn.dtripstartdate >= '2018-12-01 00:00:00.000'
    and tn.dtripstartdate < '2019-01-01 00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: Don't mix old school joins with modern ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your `from` clause:

```
from tripnumber tn,
     tripresources tr join
     (select r.ctripnumber, sum(Revenue_Subtotal) as "Revenue" 
      from (select r.ctripnumber, r.cmethod, sum(r.curevenue) as Revenue_Subtotal
            from revenuedtl r 
            where r.cmethod in (select distinct r.cmethod from revenuedtl r)
            group by r.ctripnumber, r.cmethod
           ) r
    --where r.cmethod like 'BROK%'
      group by r.ctripnumber
     ) tRev
     on tRev.ctripnumber = tn.ctripnumber
```

Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

So, rewrite this use a proper `JOIN`:

```
from tripnumber tn join
     tripresources tr
     on tn.ctripnumber = tr.ctripnumber join
     (select r.ctripnumber, sum(Revenue_Subtotal) as "Revenue" 
      from (select r.ctripnumber, r.cmethod, sum(r.curevenue) as Revenue_Subtotal
            from revenuedtl r 
            where r.cmethod in (select distinct r.cmethod from revenuedtl r)
            group by r.ctripnumber, r.cmethod
           ) r
    --where r.cmethod like 'BROK%'
      group by r.ctripnumber
     ) tRev
     on tRev.ctripnumber = tn.ctripnumber
```

And your error will go away.

The technical reason why your query fails is that the scoping rules for `,` are different from `CROSS JOIN`.  You could actually replace the comma with `CROSS JOIN` to fix the problem.  But the right solution is to express your joins correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This is a comment that doesn't fit in the comments section. Try not to mix old-schools JOINs with modern joins. It makes it more difficult to read and to debug.

For example change this:

```
from tripnumber tn,tripresources tr
where tn.ctripnumber = tr.ctripnumber
```

To this:

```
from tripnumber tn
join tripresources tr on tn.ctripnumber = tr.ctripnumber
```